# Is there function like :hover which checks ifs its clicked right now or not ? Without javascript, only CSS, HTML

Tags: html, css

Is there function like hover or something, which checks ifs special area (`div` or something) is clicked right now or not ?
I have some `div`'s with some text and other data, and if i click 1 of them, i want it to do my special stuff after clicking.
For example there are 2 `div`'s, if i click first it has to do something for me. (i have a lot of data in that `div`, not only `textarea`, `input texts`, also `buttons` etc.)

OR is it possible to check if Iclicked `div`'s area? If yes i want to do transform:scale of its area in css (multiplying size)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.a:active{
    color: brown;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
you text
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about `:focus`?

You do have to set the `div`'s `tabindex` property to let it receive focus, however.

Example:

```css
div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid;
    display: inline-block;
    tabindex: 0;
}
div:focus {
  transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);;
}
```

```html
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
```